# Google Analytics Goals: Equals to vs. Begins with

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to troubleshoot two destination goals that are exactly the same, except for one uses an "exact match" & relative url (/contact/) and the other uses "begins with" & fully-resolved url (http://www.example.com/contact/).

The exact match isn't returning any results, whereas the begins with recorded 400 conversions within the same 7-day period. I'm not 100% sure, but I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that "exact match" is much stricter than "begins with", and I know that if you have query strings in the URL, it won't trigger an "exact match" goal. Is this correct? Or is there something else that I'm missing?

This leads me to the question - do UTMs count as query strings that fail to trigger "exact match" goals? i.e. if I set up a destination goal with "exact match" /contact/ and sent traffic there via a UTM www.example.com/contact/?utm_source=email&utm_campaign=examplevideo, would that trigger the goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "exact match" goal needs to precisely match the URL.  If there's any difference, the goal won't be triggered.

I tend to use the Begins With and Regular Expression options, moreso the latter because I'm familiar with regex.  If the goal page is /contact/, a match pattern of:

^/contact/

...will match any page that begins with /contact/ regardless of what comes after it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm interested in learning more about using regular expressions since they seem to give you much more control - do you have any recommendations for resources to look into?

Comment: Sure, start here:  http://www.analyticsmarket.com/blog/regular-expressions-for-google-analytics

Comment: And then you can test regex statements here:  http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester